# Array passing only last variable

Tags: php

I am working on retrieving and parsing some data from an API. I can get the data in and function it to an array. I can then display the data in a form. However, when I go to process from the form I am only returning the last array function instead of the desired response. Any ideas?

Here is the section, I am having troubles with.

** Note the information comes in from the API in a less than desirable format so I have to clean that before posting to my forms.

```
$info = array();

$byline = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($byline as $i=> $value) {

if ($value !=""){
$info[] = $value ;
} 

if ($info !=""){
$number = array();
foreach ($info as $newdata){
$row = explode(",", $newdata);
$number[] = $row[0];
}

echo "<table style='border' cellspacing=0 cellpading=1> 
<form method=POST action=numberfinal.php name = Number>
<input type=hidden name=CUST value=$CUST>
<tr><td><input readonly name=number value=$number[0]></td>
<td>$rate</td><td>$CUST</td><td><input type=submit value=Order name=Order></td></select> 
</tr> 

<tr><td><input readonly name=number value=$number[1]></td><td>$rate</td><td>$CUST</td>   <td><input type=submit value=Order name=Order></td></select> 
</tr> 

<tr><td><input readonly name=number value=$number[2]></td><td>$rate</td><td>$CUST</td> <td><input type=submit value=Order name=Order></td></select> 
</tr> 

<tr><td><input readonly name=number value=$number[3]></td><td>$rate</td><td>$CUST</td> <td><input type=submit value=Order name=Order></td></select> 
</tr> 

</table>";
```

** To be more clear, no matter which submit I press (row 1 or row 4) the same number is passed through to my post. I would like to ensure that the appropriate number gets pass through, i.e. $number[0] or $number[4] depending on which submit is requested **

Comment: your inputs have the same name so overwrite each other

Comment: Perhaps you mean to name those inputs as an array: `name='number[]'`

Comment: Just a tidbit comment but I feel you are going about making your table rows in a very redundant way. From what it looks like, you are simply creating the same row but with different input values. Why not use a for loop rather than echoing every single one? As for your actual question, I think Dagon is right.

Comment: learning to write valid html would help also :-)

Comment: I had this as a for loop but wanted to ensure that I was not causing a trouble with my loop and overwriting data so I forced the first 4 responses from the API rather than the 103 records that were provided by the API and in the for loop. With each method the same result.

Using an array as the name=number[] field is going to return a less than favorable result on my post end as I am getting all of the data of the for each and would have to account for each possible click as a separate post statement (which would be fine if I wanted to limit to say 5 records)

Comment: would it be more beneficial to just write the API data to a temporary file or database table then pull from that and post? I am really looking for the best way to extract just the one item and then turn around and post that item back to the API.

Operating Scenario is:  Query API for availability of a product (working), get from API response of products available (working), display that list to client (working), allow them to select product they wish (NOT WORKING), post that product to API for ordering (api call works, problem is getting only last product).

Comment: its often considered good practice to embed php into html, not html into php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each `INPUT` element a different name, so that you can retrieve them each when processing the form. If this is an array of similar inputs, the way to do this is to add `[]` to the end of the input name; PHP will automatically build an array in `$_POST` for them:

```
<input readonly name='number' value='$number[3]'>
```

When you're processing the form, use:

```
foreach ($_POST['number'] as $number)
```

to process each of the entries.